# How to find duplicate ContactNo exist in my table or not

Tags: sql

how can i find if my table has duplicate records for ContactNo for given table below in sql query?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblInquiry](
[Pk_InquiryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Source] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Purpose] [varchar](50) NULL,
[InterestedIn] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OccupCat] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Possession] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ModeOfFinance] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Budget] [varchar](50) NULL,
[FK_InquiryForSite] [int] NOT NULL,
[PartyFirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PartyLastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ContactNo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EmailID] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Address] [varchar](250) NULL,
[LastAddendedBY] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateOfInquiry] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[NextFollowedUpDate] [datetime] NULL,
[LastRemark] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
[ImagePath] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[Status] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[IsSiteVisited] [bit] NULL,
[Reference] [varchar](100) NULL,
[SourceDetail] [varchar](50) NULL,
[AttendedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Rating] [tinyint] NULL,
[FK_SiteStructureId] [int] NULL,
[Fk_SourceId] [int] NULL,
[ImagePath2] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[IsFromVisitForm] [tinyint] NULL)
```

i have also foreign key in below table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblInquiryRemarks](
    [Pk_InqRemarks] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FollowedUpDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FollowedUpBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Fk_SiteId] [int] NULL,
    [Fk_InquiryId] [int] NOT NULL references tblInquiry(Pk_InquiryID),
    [Remarks] [varchar](250) NOT NULL)
```

and if exist how to delete first record for all duplicate entries in one query?

Comment: We don't do your homework for you. You might want to start reading our documentation on SQL (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/topics) to learn how to write a basic query.

Comment: i have edited question please refer.. EJoshuaS, Chris, Roma Doskoch, EdChum, greg-449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For knowing how to do this in the future refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) :)

```
select firstname as ClientName, u.userid ,count(d.Id) documents_count
from tbl_userinfo u
left join tbl_documents d
on u.Id = d.UserId
where d.ReviewStatus = 1
group by name, u.userid
```

(Couldn't really see all the fields so see if it needs to be changed)

Comment: thanks  for the answer...

Comment: @SaurabhSolanki - did it solve your problem?

Comment: sorry, but i havent tried it

Comment: i found this solution

Comment: ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetClientDocuments]
@CompanyId int
As
Begin 
select distinct d.UserID,firstname as ClientName,
(select count(*) from tbl_documents dc where dc.UserId=d.userid and dc.ReviewStatus=1) as PendingDocument
from tbl_documents d 
inner join tbl_UserInfo u on U.USERID=d.userid
End

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.ClientName , count(b.Id) , a.UserId 
from       tbl_userinfo  as a 
left join  tbl_documents as b on a.UserId = b.UserId 
group by a.ClientName , a.UserId
```

Comment: thank you for the answer